# How does the Structure block work?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Recently, Minecraft 1.10.0 has been released. And I saw a new block called structure block:

[image: A Structure Block]

I am wondering: how does the structure block work? I right-clicked it and saw something called "data" and there are 3 more other modes, it's something like save and etc.

So how does the structure block and it's 4 modes work?

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty of videos on YouTube, explaining everything you may need to know and even more, as well as more information on the Minecraft wiki. But to explain it really basically.

**Data mode** is the most complex one, I won't be covering it here.

**Save mode** lets you save a structure in a cube area up to 32x32x32 blocks with a custom name.

**Load mode** can paste structures you saved previously, rotating and mirroring them (can't flip them upside down though), or even removing some percentage of blocks.

Finally, the **Corner mode** helps you set second corner of your copy area.

In any case, you can find more info here:

- [Official minecraft wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Structure_Block)
- [Youtube tutorial by Logdotzip](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Rlnx4cTc0yo)

Comment: May someone add to this list this amazing video by Xisumavoid? There are people that get an head ache from listening to Logdotzip... https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8tC8KmJAiDg